# Trying to determine equivalence of two definitions of multiplication for integers modulo $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Consider an integer modulo $n$, defined in terms of the following coset of the integer group with addition operation, for a coset representative $a$:
$$\overline{a} = \{a + k n \, | \, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

We define $\overline{b}$ similarly, where $a, b < n$. Multiplication is defined in this way: $\overline{a} \cdot \overline{b} \equiv \overline{a b}$, where the latter $a b$ employs the usual integer multiplication (I use $\equiv$ to mean "is defined as"). See for example Dummit & Foote, Preliminaries section.

I wanted to check if this is equivalent to the following definition (I don't think it is in general, but am having trouble showing whether it is or it isn't):
$$\overline{a} * \overline{b} \equiv \{xy \, | \, x \in \overline{a}, y \in \overline{b}\}$$

If you write out my second proposed definition explicitly for the set members, you'll see that whether it is equivalent seems to rest on whether the following equation has integer solutions $(k,l)$ for all $N \in \mathbb{Z}$:
$$ a l + b k + n k l = N$$

Whether this has integer solutions for all $N$ determines whether the resulting set is equal to the coset $\overline{a b}$ that results from the first (standard) definition. This looks like a nonlinear diophantine equation or the like, which I haven't dealt with before. I feel like I'm overthinking this or am missing something.

**Edit**: It was requested that I show how I obtained the equation and why it must have solutions for all $N$. From my definition of $*$, we have:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\overline{a}*\overline{b} &\equiv& \{x y \, | x \in \overline{a}, y \in \overline{b}\} \\
&=& \{ (a + kn)(b + l n) \, | \, k,l \in \mathbb{Z} \} \\
&=& \{ ab + (a l + b k + n k l) n \, | \, k,l \in \mathbb{Z} \} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

If the definitions are equivalent, the set in the last equality must be the same as $\{ab+Nn \, | \, N \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. For this to be true, $a l + b k + n k l$ must span all the integers just as $N$ does. So, $a l + b k + n k l$ must be surjective on $\mathbb{Z}$, and therefore $a l + b k + n k l = N$ must have integer solutions $(k,l)$ for all integers $N$. Recall that $a$, $b$, and $n$ are all fixed.

Comment: Please work out how you got to the equation $al+bk+nkl=N$ and why it must be solveable for all $N$ to get an equivalent definition! If $k$ and $l$ are not coprime, we cannot have a solution for all $N$.

Comment: @Peter Sure, will edit to add that in.

Comment: @Peter Apologies as well, because when I first wrote the question, I referred to the natural numbers \mathbb{N}, when I meant the integers \mathbb{Z} throughout ... It was roughly three in the morning when I wrote the question :) I edited to correct that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it isn't. Working mod $5$, we get $\overline 2\cdot\overline 2=\overline 4=\{5k+4\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$.

So $19\in\overline 4$, but $19\not\in\{xy\mid x,y\in\overline 2\}$, since the only ways to express $19$ as a product are $1\cdot19$ and $(-1)\cdot(-19)$, and none of these factors are in $\overline 2$.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the counter-example!

Comment: @SherifF. Did I notice right that you accepted this answer ? Why is it unaccepted now ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I undid it though as I thought it was probably good protocol to wait just a little bit to give a chance to any others to write answers since the question is so fresh (I'm not sure what the standard protocol is - I don't use this site as frequently as I probably should). :)

Comment: @SherifF. Well, you decide it at the end! But there is no reason to hesitate when you think that an answer should be accepted. And I do no think, that a better answer will occur.

Comment: @Peter Questioners do not often have the experience to judge if a better answer amy occur. Generally it is much better to wait a while before accepting, since many experienced readers do not answer quickly, and they may not bother to open threads that already have accepted answers.

Answer (score 2):

No, in general your $\overline{a}*\overline{b}$ is only a subset of $\overline{ab}$, and the inclusion can be strict. Think of the square of the zero element of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$: multiplying two even numbers together always produces a multiple of $2^2=4$, and not all even numbers have this property. Note that the same counterexample works in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ for any integer $n>1$, simply replacing $2$ by$~n$.

Comment: Great - thanks for the family of counterexamples!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ If $\ c\mid a,b,n,\ \color{#c00}{c^2\nmid n}\ $ then $\,c^2\!\mid\! (a\!+\!in)(b\!+\!jn)\ $ but $\ c^2\nmid ab\!+\!n\in ab+n\Bbb Z\ $ (else $\,\color{#c00}{c^2\mid n})$